# Shortly submenu list and create links to opened all

Tags: submenu

I want to creates submenu like this:

http://cdn.kaskus.com/images/2014/03/16/1148109_20140316095755.jpg how to implement on php?
my codes is look like below

```
<{foreach item=sublist from=$cList.scat key=nums}>

    <li><a >/<{$sublist.catid}>/<{$sublist.cat}>"><{$sublist.cat}></a></li>

<{/foreach}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done!

```
...
<{foreach item=sublist from=$cList.scat key=nums}>
 <{if $nums<5}>
  <li><a href="<{$sublist.catid}>/<{$sublist.cat}>"><{$sublist.cat}></a></li>
 <{/if}>
 <{/foreach}>
 <a href="url">View All Categories</a>
```